# Change CSS property (like background colour) for overlapping DIVs

Tags: css, overlap, highlighting

I have a calendar-style app that displays events as colour-coded DIVs of varying lengths absolutely positioned on a timeline. These events must not overlap. I want to be able to highlight overlaps via CSS. For example, non-overlapping events normally display with a green background, but if one gets scheduled to overlap the other (completely or partially) I want both to change to, say, orange.
Is there a CSS way to do this or must I examine the events themselves for conflicts? (I know how to do the latter, but it just seems that there should be a CSS solution.)

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone. You need JavaScript.

Comment: You'd need to do this server side when generating the calendar; add a class name to the `div` of any event that clashes with and then set the `background-color` for that class to orange.